# Ctrl-W in vim dont work in insert mode in terminal

Tags: vim, ubuntu

when I use Ctrl-W (or Ctrl-H) in insert mode it does nothing. In gvim with the same vimrc works. I'm using Ubuntu 10.4 with gnome, what may be wrong?

Comment: You could try `vim -u NONE` to see if it's an issue with your `.vimrc` or `~/.vim/`

Comment: no, it looks like a terminal issue

Comment: Can you try CTRL+V then CTRL+W to check if the character is ^W is displayed ?

Comment: ^W is not displayed..., but at my friend with same system C-W works, it have to be some my settings...

Comment: Can you try CTRL+V then CTRL+W in bash?

Comment: Solved in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344557/strange-problem-with-backspace-in-vim

Answer (score 2):

Try adding to your `.vimrc`: `set backspace=indent,eol,start`

Answer (score 1):

Type this from normal mode:

`:verbose map`<kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>C-w</kbd>Enter

This will tell you two things:

- you will see what your terminal emits for <kbd>C-w</kbd> (it is shown on the vim command line before you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- it will tell you whether <kbd>C-w</kbd> has any mappings in any mode
- it will tell you where the mapping comes from

Subsequently look at

`:verbose iabbrev`

to see whether abbreviations are in the way

Answer (score 0):

just try type "i" or "a"
maybe you terminal has reserved these key binds?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, took me a while to figure that out.