# Strange problem with backspace in vim

Tags: vim

I can use backspace or C-h only in current insert mode - when I change to normal mode and then to insert I can not use it :( Whats wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in your `vimrc`:

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```